# Write a function which calculates the input array passes ar least one rule as below in Java

Tags: java

Write a function which calculates the input array passes at least one rule as below.

1-horizontal:each row is identical.

2-vertical: each column is identical.

3-diagonal left: each item is identical to the one on its upper left or bottom right.

4-diagonal right: each item is identical to the one on its upper right or bottom left.

Example:

```
     AA AA AA -> horizantally equal

     AB AB AB -> AB
                 AB  vertically equal
                 AB

     ABC BAC CBA -> ABC
                    BAC  diagonal left
                    CBA
```

```
String[] arr = new String[]{"AB", "AB", "AB"};
        
        //checking horizontaly
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
        if(set.size() == 1) 
            System.out.println("All equal");
        else 
            System.out.println("All not equal");
```

I tried to come up with a solution for horizontal rule.

I created a hashset and put all elements into the set and then I checked the size of the set. If it is equals to 1 then all elements must be equal since sets in java does not allow duplicate values. But I don't have any idea for other rules. What should I do?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use for-loops to achieve this.

Consider the following methods.

```java
boolean horizontal(String[] strings) {
    String horizontal = strings[0];
    for (String string : strings) {
        if (!string.equals(horizontal))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```java
boolean vertical(String[] strings) {
    char vertical;
    for (int index = 0; index < strings[0].length(); index++) {
        vertical = strings[index].charAt(index);
        for (String string : strings) {
            if (string.charAt(index) != vertical)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

```java
boolean diagonalLeft(String[] strings) {
    char diagonal = strings[0].charAt(0);
    return strings[strings.length - 1].charAt(strings[0].length() - 1) == diagonal;
}
```

```java
boolean diagonalRight(String[] strings) {
    char diagonal = strings[strings.length - 1].charAt(0);
    return strings[0].charAt(strings[0].length() - 1) == diagonal;
}
```

Here is an example.

```java
String[] stringsA = new String[] { "AA", "AA", "AA" };
String[] stringsB = new String[] { "AB", "AB", "AB" };
String[] stringsC = new String[] { "ABC", "BAC", "CBA" };

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringsA));
System.out.println("horizontal = " + horizontal(stringsA));
System.out.println("vertical = " + vertical(stringsA));
System.out.println("diagonalLeft = " + diagonalLeft(stringsA));
System.out.println("diagonalRight = " + diagonalRight(stringsA));
System.out.println();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringsB));
System.out.println("horizontal = " + horizontal(stringsB));
System.out.println("vertical = " + vertical(stringsB));
System.out.println("diagonalLeft = " + diagonalLeft(stringsB));
System.out.println("diagonalRight = " + diagonalRight(stringsB));
System.out.println();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringsC));
System.out.println("horizontal = " + horizontal(stringsC));
System.out.println("vertical = " + vertical(stringsC));
System.out.println("diagonalLeft= " + diagonalLeft(stringsC));
System.out.println("diagonalRight = " + diagonalRight(stringsC));
```

Output

```
[AA, AA, AA]
horizontal = true
vertical = true
diagonalLeft = true
diagonalRight = true

[AB, AB, AB]
horizontal = true
vertical = true
diagonalLeft = false
diagonalRight = false

[ABC, BAC, CBA]
horizontal = false
vertical = false
diagonalLeft= true
diagonalRight = true
```